# View XML Request when using WSClient and Rules

Tags: services, debugging

I am building a website that uses 3rd party data from a web service. I decided to use WSClient...so far so good.

I am using Rules together with WSClient to create the proper SOAP request, however I am having issues debugging the requests (they are returning errors) because I can't figure out how to view the actual XML. Using Devel, I can see the values in the data structures I am creating, but I can't figure out how to view the XML itself, thus I'm not sure if I've built out the structure properly.

I've looked here, https://www.drupal.org/node/1801200, but haven't quite figured out how to see the XML.

Any idea or leads on how to trace or view the XML itself would be appreciated.

Thanks.

P.S. I come from a product management/ui/design background, so please pardon me if any of this seems obvious.